# angular material custom inputs for mat-date-range-picker

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I must have two custom separated inputs for `mat-date-range-picker`.
It should look in this way: (I know how to write this css)

[image]

I know how to write this css.
But the problem is that I can't get value of this datepicker. It seems like I have to use `mat-range-input` with material inputs only. And I also have to use `matStartDate` `matEndDate`.

It means that there should be this snippet of code:

```html
<mat-date-range-input>
  <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
  <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
</mat-date-range-input>
```

but i gotta have 2 custom separated inputs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hided the mat-date-range with `opacity: 0` and got the values from it